# Xfce - Lock the screen on suspend but not on hibernate

Tags: xfce, manjaro, suspend, screen-lock

I am trying to get xfce to lock my screen on suspend, but not on hibernate.
As I am using full disk encryption, I need to enter a password after hibernation to unlock my SSD (and I don't want to enter two passwords), but after suspending, my system currently does not require a password.

The "Lock screen when system is going to sleep" option under security in the xfce power manager only works for both suspending and hibernating, not for just suspending. Is there a way to achieve this?

I am using Manjaro Xfce with LightDm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, yesterday I accidentally stumbled accross [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/925720) on askubuntu.com, and one of the answer uses `dm-tool lock` ( after setting `XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0`) to lock the screen from a script in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`.
After adapting this a bit, I came up with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ "$1" == "pre" ]]; then
    pkill intel-virtual
    sleep 1
    if [[ "$2" != "hibernate" ]]; then
        XDG_SEAT_PATH="/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0" dm-tool lock 
    fi
    sleep 1
fi
```

(Note:  `pkill intel-virtual; sleep 1`  is only necessary due to my specific hardware setup using Nvidia hybrid graphics. Most other people should be able to delete those lines.)

Putting this in an executable script in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` solves my issue.