# waylock - Trigger screenlocker on suspend, but not on hibernate?

Tags: wayland, laptop, systemd-unit

The rationale is the same as in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583169/xfce-lock-the-screen-on-suspend-but-not-on-hibernate) - since I'm already typing a disk encryption password on resume, I don't want to have to unlock my screen as well. I want the screen locker to only trigger on suspend.

Currently I am using a systemd service file in `/etc/systemd/system/user/suspend@service`, as described [in the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management#Sleep_hooks) -

```
# systemctl --user enable suspend@myusername.service
[Unit]
Description=Suspend actions
Before=suspend.target

[Service]
User=%I
Environment=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-1
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/waylock -fork-on-lock

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

The problem is that `suspend.target` seems to be pulled in on hibernation as well, so this triggers on hibernation.

Is there any other way to get the result I want?